# How to display loaded CSS/JS Rails assets in production as is in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

When I open my Rails app and display the generated HTML code, I see there every single CSS file that is loaded.

In production mode I see only on **application.css** file where is everything.

How to display the same statement that is in the development mode also in production?

The reason why I want to do that is, that the CSS structure of the application looks differently on my localhost and on Amazon AWS. I prepared all CSS for the app locally, where was everything pixel-perfect prepared, but when I deployed the code to AWS, the app looks different - font (from Google fonts) is bigger (although I see there is used the same size), the same for some DIVs... don't know how to figure this out, so trying to inspect all loaded CSS files.

Comment: Have you read the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) guide ?

Answer (score 0):

Your have to disable asset pipelining from config/environments/production.rb

config.assets.enabled = false

Answer (score 0):

First did you compile the assets during Deployment

Please read the docs
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

For development style css files
You might want to set these

config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true

**NOTE: Dont use these permanently  its just to start with asset pipeline or debug**